# Replace all spaces with a new line in CMD

Tags: windows, string, parsing, command-line, cmd

I have a input file of type .txt :

```
// file.txt
The quick brown dog jumped over the lazy fox.
```

---

Basically I want to use this input file to produce an output file with each string quote-enclosed and on its own line in CMD. Any ideas?

Output should be like this:

```
'The'

'quick'

 etc...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
set /p text=<file.txt
(for %%i in (%text%) do echo '%%i')>newfile.txt
```

Comment: Awesome! How about saving that output to a file? @Stephan

Comment: Hey, do you know how I would go about doing this with a custom delim (such a `&`) instead of spaces separating words?

Comment: @rahuldottech: if your data doesn't contain spaces, replace `%text%` with `%text:@= %`, where `@` is your custom delimiter. (won't work with `&` and other poison characters, because they are treated differently) If you need `&` and/or your data contains spaces, use another approach.

Comment: @Stephan Unfortunately, my text does contain `&`s. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

**I note now that the terms were supposed to be enclosed in single quotes - which the code below doesn't do.  It just does what the subject line asks and separates each term on a new line by itself.**

Here is a more robust solution that handles poison characters, and retains all characters in the file, and is far quicker on large files.

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat`  ([preview as gist](https://gist.github.com/hakre/04d034840eae937d2a26) or [download from dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat))

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
type "file.txt" |repl " " "\r\n" x >"newfile.txt"
```